# Performance: XmlSerializer vs XmlReader vs XmlDocument vs XDocument

Tags: .net, linq-to-xml, xmldocument, xmlserializer, xmlreader

I'm working on a little web project and would like to read/write to an XML file. Performance is my first priority.

I've come to [this great post](http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/joe_ferner/performance_linq_to_sql_vs.html) on comparing the mentioned approaches except `XmlSerializer`.

I prefer `XmlSerializer` since it makes the code much cleaner. But I don't know about its performance. What kind does `XmlSerializer` use inside to write to XML files?

Comment: `XmlReader` will be faster than any serializer.

Comment: Wouldn't a better question be:  "Here's my experiment.  Are there any flaws in my implementations?"

Comment: I think that if performance is important, vtd-xml should be worth investigating for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for the performance of XmlSerializer, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx which says:

> The XmlSerializer creates C# files and
>   compiles them into .dll files to
>   perform this serialization. In .NET
>   Framework 2.0, the XML Serializer
>   Generator Tool (Sgen.exe) is designed
>   to generate these serialization
>   assemblies in advance to be deployed
>   with your application and improve
>   startup performance.

So you can increase performance of XmlSerializer by making use of the sgen tool http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240.aspx, that way you can avoid the performance hit you get when new XmlSerializer() creates and compiles C# files.